# How to print user input in malbolge?

Tags: malbolge

Finally, after some months of research I accept user input, but now I'm trying to print it in the screen.
Is that possible using Malbolge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy like this:

```
(=BA#9"=<;:3y7x54-21q/p-,+*)"!h%B0/.~P<<:(8&66#"!~}|{zyxwvugJ%
```

(Malbolge cat program, public domain)